# kibana data starts at an extremely high (and unreal) value

Tags: logstash, kibana

The data in my kibana graphs seem to start with a massive extreme value.  This value doesn't actually exist in the dataset.

Regardless of where I zoom the timeframe, this anomaly exists.  Eg. the graph on the left has more data (values closer to zero) from earlier times, but zooming in on an area that appears to be all <100 still results in this giant data spike at the beginning of the timeline.

[image: 1]

Comment: I've flushed/deleted all of the Elasticsearch data and started over.  Issue remains.

Comment: Weird. If you place the sampling events in a table panel, you don't see these extreme values? what Kibana version you are using?

Comment: That's correct, they don't appear.  Kibana is the latest version as of today.